# c#: Log4Net console application failed to create console color according log level and crash

Tags: c#, console-application, log4net

So this is my `Log4Net` `app.config`:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%date] [%level] [%logger/%method] → %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
      <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <foreColor value="Orange, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <foreColor value="Green, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <foreColor value="Yellow, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <foreColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:\logs\log.txt"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%date] [%level] - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

So all works fine except the fact that i cannot create any `Console color` that i want.

for example:

```
  <mapping>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <foreColor value="Orange, HighIntensity" />
  </mapping>
```

When i try to define this `Orange` (or even `Gray`) color i received this error:

> log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [ConsoleAppender] of type
>   [log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender]. Reported error follows.
>   System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'Orange, HighIntensity' was
>   not found.    at System.Enum.EnumResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind
>   failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument)
>   at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)    at System.Enum.Parse(Type
>   enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   log4net.Util.OptionConverter.ConvertStringTo(Type target, String txt) 
>   at
>   log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ConvertStringTo(Type
>   type, String value)    at
>   log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.SetParameter(XmlElement
>   element, Object target)    at
>   log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.CreateObjectFromXml(XmlElement
>   element, Type defaultTargetType, Type typeConstraint)    at
>   log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.SetParameter(XmlElement
>   element, Object target)    at
>   log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement
>   appenderElement) log4net:ERROR Appender named [ConsoleAppender] not
>   found.

But if i want to define `Blue` this works fine without any `errors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, Orange is not a valid color that could be used: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender.html

Excerpt from the link:
The Level is the standard log4net logging level and ForeColor and BackColor can be any combination of the following values:

Blue -
Green -
Red -
White -
Yellow -
Purple -
Cyan -
HighIntensity